# How to fix Flexbox styles in IE 11

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11, frontend

I'm using flexbox here - http://marcinzalewski.net/exo/ but I can't fix this for IE 11. Even Microsoft Edge is working fine and IE 11 is only version I need to fix.

My flex-container look like this:

```
.flex-container {
  max-width: 1240px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
}
```

And this is my inside elements code:

```
.offer-element {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
```

Now those elements should be centered and fit in few lines, but they all are in the same line and have ~150px instead of 250px each. I tried to add display: -ms-flexbox; but it doesn't work anyway. Normally they are all centered and take 3 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're specifying flex-wrap only on webkit. By default flex will fit all items one line. You need to specify `flex-wrap: wrap` on your container.

Comment: If you haven't come across this, I've found it to be very useful: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I can't believe it was so easy, thank you very much for your help, everything works fine now!

Comment: your welcome :) please mark the correct answer so others can benefit if they've got the same issue

Answer (score 1):

IE 11 requires a unit to be added to the third argument, the flex-basis property

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn254946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx